# COMException (0x80004005): Slides (unknown member) : Failed thrown in InsertFromFile method

Tags: interop, powerpoint

I'm working with powerpoint presentations using `Microsoft Interop library`. Exception from title is thrown on adding slide to presentation via Interop library method.

File exists, path is correct, index is valid.

```cs
inpPre.Slides.InsertFromFile(tmpPathInsert, inpSldCom.SlideIndex);
```

This code worked as it has to for plenty of presentations and throws exception on specific slides.
Error:

```cs
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Slides (unknown member) : Failed.
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slides.InsertFromFile(String FileName, Int32 Index, Int32 SlideStart, Int32 SlideEnd)
```

Any thoughts on why is this happens?

Comment: Just google "powerpoint insertfromfile failed" to find other victims.  It has a knack for failing with "runtime error 0", surely what is responsible for the miserable "Failed" diagnostic.

Answer (score 0):

The PowerPoint that the file path is pointing to does not exist. Be sure to check the path and make sure it's pointing to the file you want to use. I recommend following the path exactly to see where it leads and make sure the file exists there.